# SerializationBinder to ignore unknown types from foreign assembly

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization

I need to deserialize a binary file created by an other assembly. Type names are the same so on BindToType I alter the full name of the class and return a found type. It works ok, but there are some classes I don't support and I need to ignore them. If I return null, an exception is thrown as the class is not found.

The intermediate error was "SerializationException: The ObjectManager found an invalid number of fixups. This usually indicates a problem in the Formatter.".

How can I ignore unknown types and get the object deserialized in the same moment?

```
    sealed class MyAsemblyBinder : System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder
    {
        public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
        {
            string myAsm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;

            Type foundType = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, myAsm));

            return foundType;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring types during the serialization is possible by forcing a cast to a generic object during the deserialization. To do that the binder must return type of object.

Full code would look like this:

```
    sealed class MyAsemblyBinder : System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder
    {
        public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
        {
            string myAsm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;

            Type foundType = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, myAsm));

            if (foundType == null)
                foundType = typeof(Object);

            return foundType;
        }
    }
```